# How to Implement Specific Actions for Floating Action Button Depending on the Current Screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter app with a `BottomNavigationBar` that allows users to navigate between different screens (`HomeScreen`, `ProfileScreen`, and `SettingsScreen`). I want to implement a `FloatingActionButton` in the `MyHomePage` widget that performs different actions based on which screen is currently displayed. The different actions themselves are defined in the corresponding pages as functions (`HomeScreen`, `ProfileScreen`, `SettingsScreen`).

For instance:

- On the `HomeScreen`, the FAB might open a new post dialog.
- On the `ProfileScreen`, it might navigate to the edit profile page.
- On the `SettingsScreen`, it might open the app's settings.

How can I make the FAB's onPressed function aware of the current screen and execute the specific logic associated with that screen?

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _screens = [
    HomeScreen(),
    ProfileScreen(),
    SettingsScreen(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My App'),
      ),
      body: _screens[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: 'Profile',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            label: 'Settings',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text('Home Screen'),
    );
  }
}

class ProfileScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text('Profile Screen'),
    );
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text('Settings Screen'),
    );
  }
}
```

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you can pass the _currentIndex to a method that returns a FloatingActionButton with the callback that you want, something like this:

```dart
FloatingActionButton? buildFloatingActionButton(
  int index,
  VoidCallback homeScreenCallback,
  VoidCallback profileScreenCallback,
  VoidCallback settingsScreenCallback,
) {
  if (index == 0) {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () => homeScreenCallback,
      child: const Icon(Icons.home),
    );
  } else if (index == 1) {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () => profileScreenCallback,
      child: const Icon(Icons.user),
    );
  } else if (index == 2) {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () => settingsScreenCallback,
      child: const Icon(Icons.settings),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if the typing is correct, but this idea should work since your widget is Stateful so it will update the FAB once the index changes.

You can then call this function in your Scaffold:

```
floatingActionButton: buildFloatingActionButton(_selectedIndex),
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways:

1. You can use State Management (preserve current index)
2. simply pass _currentIndex  to all the pages. (not that good)

Simplest Way is Create a Floating Action Button in **MyHomePage** 's Scaffold

Example:

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My App'),
      ),
      body: _screens[_currentIndex],
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                     switch (_currentIndex) {
                        case 0: // Page 1 Work
                          
                          break;

                         case 1: // Page 2 Work
                          
                          break;

                          case 2:
                                // Page 3 Work
                          break;

                        default:
                        //Any Default Work
                      }
                    },
                  
                    child: Your UI //
```

Comment: Creating the FAB is not the problem but how to call the function from the other page in a clean way?

Comment: you can call the functions in the switch case statements. This will be cleaner. Else you should look for a using provider.

Comment: How can you call the functions if the functions need an instance of `HomeScreen`, `ProfileScreen`,...?